# Overheard while hiking

Tags: wordplay, english

I was hiking in the desert this weekend and saw two people coming the other way. We nodded and smiled as we passed, and, as sometimes happens in these situations, I overheard a snippet of their conversation.

Person 1: Granite is not nice.

Person 2: I think granite is lovely.

Person 1: Me too.

I couldn't make head or tail of this. What could they possibly mean.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Person 1 is taunting Person 2 for

> Having a less thorough understanding of Geology, via the phrase Granite is not Gneiss (a metamorphic rock that is sometimes formed from Granite) Person 2 is reasonably confused by the homophone, and even more confused by Person 1's response.

Comment: Huh.  I always that it was pronounced like the French city.

Answer (score 6):

What you didn't hear:

> The actual beginning of Person 1's first statement.
> Person 1: *Some people think* granite is not nice.
> Person 2: I think granite is lovely.
> Person 1: Me too.

Comment: The [tag:wordplay] tag means that there is wordplay, this is just modifying the snippet, not playing with its words at all.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Of course it is: It's reinterpreting the first "sentence" as a content clause! Wowee!

Answer (score 0):

I believe they were talking about what a great rock granite is for climbing. Because its good weathering, the diverse challenges and degrees of difficulty it poses for a climber, it is considered one of the best kind of rocks for climbing.

Comment: Note the [tag:wordplay] tag ...